# Merge columns or rows in php generated table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a generate table like this:

```
Model#   |   Description   |    Height   |    Width   |    Length
Item 1   |   standard      |      5      |     3      |     1
Item 2   |   special       |             |            |       
Item 3   |   plastic       |             |            |
```

So every item's height, width and length are the same. So I am trying to figure out how to merge the "height", "width" and "length" coz 3 items are all 5 x 3 x 1. Thanks!

This is the code:

```
function PrintProductTable($productResult, $productDetails, $headArr)
        {

            $productDetails = populteGeneralToDetail($productResult, $productDetails);

            echo "<table class=\"chart\" >";
            echo "<tr>";

            for($i=0; $i<count($headArr); $i++)
                echo "<th>".$headArr[$i]."</th>";

            echo "</tr>";
            foreach($productDetails as $modelName=>$productDetail)
            {
                echo "<tr>";

                for($i=0; $i<count($headArr); $i++)
                {
                    $col = $headArr[$i];
                    $value;
                    if (array_key_exists($col, $productDetail))
                        $value = $productDetail[$col];      

                    else 
                        $value = "" ;                       


                    echo "<td>".$value."</td>";

                }

                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: what u mean by merge the columns ?

Comment: You're missing the actual question. What we have to look into?

Comment: Yes I am trying to merge the "height","width" and "length" coz 3 items have the same size (5 x 3 x 1). So  Sorry for the confusion.